# Increment a value on MYSQL with react node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, increment

Why does this doesn't work

```
    const increment = 'votes + 1'

    db.query("UPDATE president SET votes = ? WHERE nickname = ?",
    [increment, president], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
```

but this code below works

```
    db.query("UPDATE president SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE nickname = ?",
    [president], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
```

I just want to do the incrementing of mysql columns with votes = ?
I wanted to do it with the votes = ? way. Does anyone know the proper syntax of incrementing a value in mysql with react node js?

Comment: Your second example is how I would do it. There's no reason to use a query parameter in this case, because the expression is not based on untrusted variables, it's just a fixed expression `votes + 1`.

Comment: Besides, query parameters are not just string substitutions. They can't be used for full expressions, or column identifiers. One parameter is used only in place of a single scalar value, and that's how the SQL engine will use it. So your parameterized code behaves as if you had done `votes = 'votes + 1'` (i.e. the parameter acts like a string literal, which becomes 0 in an integer expression).